# Query With CONCAT and LOOP using SELECT

Tags: mysql, loops, concatenation

I got this kind of column:

```
------------------
|reference_number|
------------------
|1               |
|12              |
|123             |
|1234            |
|12345           |
|123456          |
|1234567         |
|12345678        |
|123456789       |
|1234567890      |
------------------
```

I want to achieve this kind of output using mysql query:

```
------------------
|reference_number|
------------------
|0000000001      |
|0000000012      |
|0000000123      |
|0000001234      |
|0000012345      |
|0000123456      |
|0001234567      |
|0012345678      |
|0123456789      |
|1234567890      |
------------------
```

What I'm doing right now:

```
SELECT CONCAT('000000000', reference_number) FROM example
```

But it will only work for 1st record, I know it will be very easy to do it using programming language such as `PHP` or `Java`, but can anyone advise how to do it using mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **[LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)**.

```
SELECT LPAD(reference_number, 10, '0') FROM example
```